# How to load some html code in webview?

Tags: android, android-webview

How to load some html code in webview?

I want to Send some `HTML` code from `MainActivity` to a `WebViewActivity` which have a `WebView` layout, I want to get the `HTML`  code and display on `webview` as a `HTML` page.
My `HTML` code is :

```
<p><span style=\"font-size: 12pt;\">Sample text<\/span><\/p>\r\n<p><span style=\"font-size: 14pt; color: #00ffff;\">Sample text<\/span><\/p>\r\n<p><span style=\"font-size: 36pt; color: #99cc00;\">Sample text<\/span><\/p>\r\n<p><span style=\"font-size: 36pt; color: #ff0000;\">Sample text<\/span><\/p>\r\n<p>&nbsp;<\/p>
```

And My `WebViewActivity` is :

```
String value;
private WebView webView;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    value = getIntent().getStringExtra(MY_EXTRA);
    Log.w(MY_EXTRA, "Data recieved is >> " + value);

    setContentView(R.layout.webview);
    this.getIntent().putExtra("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 60);       

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {             

            view.loadData(value, "text/html", null);
            return true;
        }
    });

    new getData().execute(null, null, null);

}


private class getData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(
                false);
        webView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(false);
        webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
        webView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(
                WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
        webView.getSettings().setSavePassword(false);
        webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        webView.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(200);
        webView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        webView.clearCache(true);
        // webView.clearHistory();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        webView.loadUrl(value);
    }

}
```

Now I'm unable to see any results of my `HTML` code and my `webview` does not show any thing. How to see my result? Any body!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your all the code is correct but your are mistaking in line `webView.loadUrl(value)` now set your `onPostExecute()` like this :

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        webView.loadData(value, "text/html", null);
    }
```

this works for me, hope will work for you as well.

Comment: Ooops!! that was only mistake! now it is working! thanks Ada!